# Count the number of specific values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have to count the number of 'No' in a dataframe and add that count to a separate column called 'count'.

For example:

```
 MachineName    Logs   Jobs   Performance
 121            Yes    No      Yes
 123            Yes    No      No
 126            No     No      No
```

Output:

```
 MachineName    Logs   Jobs   Performance   Count
 121            Yes    No      Yes          1
 123            Yes    No      No           2          
 126            No     No      No           3
```

I tried the following code but it does not run as expected.

```
 condition = (df[['Logs','Jobs','Performance']] == 'No').any(axis=0)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering all rows based on a specific value in Pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311665/filtering-all-rows-based-on-a-specific-value-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), because `boolean mask` is converted to `int`:

```
df['Count'] = (df[['Logs','Jobs','Performance']] == 'No').sum(axis=1)

print (df)
   MachineName Logs Jobs Performance  Count
0          121  Yes   No         Yes      1
1          123  Yes   No          No      2
2          126   No   No          No      3
```

Another solution with select all columns without first by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['Count'] = (df.iloc[:,1:] == 'No').sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   MachineName Logs Jobs Performance  Count
0          121  Yes   No         Yes      1
1          123  Yes   No          No      2
2          126   No   No          No      3
```